Unable to mount SSD after computer froze - Zorin OS
While I was watching a popout Youtube video in Firefox while moving about 81GB of files from my secondary SSD, which was a backup from when I had Windows 11, to my main drive into the documents folder, my computer suddenly froze up for about 30 seconds until I foolishly turned it off without any response from mouse or keyboard. After I turned it on again, everything was normal and some of the stuff was moved, most of it corrupt though, and I'm unable to mount the secondary SSD anymore, instead only being met with an error saying:
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/(my name)/Storage 1: Unknown Error when mounting /dev/sda1.

If you copy, and then delete old files, they'll still be on the original drive. You likely will need data recovery from the old drive, if those files are of value. However, SSD's tend to die suddenly and completely, rather than gradual failure more common on HDD , so there's a chance the SSD is dead.

It's not dead, nothing appears to be wrong with the ssd. It's still working and I'm about to use it for booting windows so I can edit videos on the same computer without having to sideload on one drive.

I found out you can just go to Disks, find the drive and repair the partition in seconds. Finished the transfer, I hope you all have a wonderful day.
